# How to bined a detailview field to a form field in django and save into database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am building this simple system for online voting, where people can vote but will have to pay for their vote cast.My current challenge is how to bined a selected candidate on a page and allowing voters to enter number of votes they went to cast for that candidate on the same page

I have tried using SingleObjectMixin but am having problem saving the form in database.
And also how can i prepopulate the select candidate to a model field name Nominee

```
model.py 
 class Award(models.Model):
STATUS_PUBLISHED = (
    ('Closed', 'Closed'),
    ('Opened', 'Opened'),
)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='award_images')
status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS_PUBLISHED,    default='Closed')

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Category(models.Model):
Award = models.ForeignKey(Award, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
category = models.CharField(max_length=100,)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.category


class Nomination(models.Model):
Fullname = models.CharField(max_length=120)
Category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='nominations_images')

def __str__(self):
    return self.Fullname


class VoteAmount(models.Model):
Nominee = models.ForeignKey(Nomination, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
votes_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.votes_amount
```

views.py

```
 from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView
 from .models import Award, Category, Nomination, VoteAmount
 from .forms import VoteAmountForm
 from django.urls import reverse
 from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden
 from django.views.generic import FormView
 from django.views.generic.detail import SingleObjectMixin
 from django.views import View


class AwardView(ListView):
template_name = 'award.html'
context_object_name = 'award_list'
queryset = Award.objects.filter(status='Opened').order_by('-date')


class CategoryView(DetailView):
model = Award
template_name = 'category.html'


class NominationView(DetailView):
model = Category
template_name = 'nomination.html'


class VoteAmountView(DetailView):
model = Nomination
template_name = 'voteamount.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(VoteAmountView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['form'] = VoteAmountForm()
    return context


class AmountView(SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
template_name = 'voteamount.html'
form_class = VoteAmountForm

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    self.object = self.get_object()
    return super(AmountView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('results', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})


class AuthorDetail(View):

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    view = VoteAmountView.as_view()
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    view = AmountView.as_view()
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)


class PaymentView(DetailView):
model = VoteAmount
template_name = 'PaymentView.html'
```

form.py

```
 from django import forms
 from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
 from .models import VoteAmount


 class VoteAmountForm(forms.ModelForm):
 class Meta:
    model = VoteAmount

    fields = ('Nominee', 'votes_amount')
```

ImproperlyConfigured at /results/fiifi-quansa

AmountView is missing a QuerySet. Define AmountView.model, AmountView.queryset, or override AmountView.get_queryset().

all i went to do is show the selected condidate as a nominee field for model VoteAmount and enter my number of votes

Answer (score 0):

As the error said:

> AmountView is missing a QuerySet. Define AmountView.model, AmountView.queryset, or override AmountView.get_queryset().

Means, you are using `SingleObjectMixin`, you need to provide a queryset/model/ override `get_queryset()` method in the class. like this:

```
class AmountView(SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'voteamount.html'
    form_class = VoteAmountForm
    queryset = Nomination.objects.all()
```

Also, you need to override [**`get_form_kwargs()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs) method to load the the initial nominee data.

```
class AmountView(SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'voteamount.html'
    form_class = VoteAmountForm
    queryset = Nomination.objects.all()

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form_kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        form_kwargs['nominee'] = self.get_object()
        return form_kwargs
```

And override `VoteAmountForm` as well to limit the choices:

```
class VoteAmountForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         nominee = kwargs.pop('nominee')
         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.fields['Nominee'].queryset = Nominee.objects.filter(pk=nominee.pk)  # <-- Please use snake_case when defining model field names(as per pep8 style guide)
         self.initial['Nominee'] = nominee

    class Meta:
         model = VoteAmount
         fields = ('Nominee', 'votes_amount')
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but am getting a new error .                                                                                                                                                                                      queryset = Nominee.objects.all()
NameError: name 'Nominee' is not defined

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve what i want without using SingleObjectMixin

Comment: Sure, there is. But, the error you are getting is not for `SingleObjectMixin`. Its because you did not import `Nominee` model in the view file.

Comment: Please i don't have a model called Nominee but rather a model field. Could you check my models and put me the right direction please.   Or better still show me other ways to do it without using    SingleObjectMixin

Comment: Opps. My bad. Updated the answer

Comment: colud you take a look at my form.py as well  i am getting an error. nominee = kwargs.pop('nominee')
KeyError: 'nominee'

Comment: Also when i remove the that section  and submit the form i get another error.     __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nominee'